# Custom icon for Google map API v3 directions

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I know how to change icon on standard google map api v3.
Is there any way to change icons on map with directions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize(){
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions={
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel")
    );

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      map: map,
      icon: 'marker/image.png',
      title: 'Click to zoom'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
      map.setZoom(15);
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = '-34.397, 150.644';
    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Above code display map with my custom icon marker but when I generate directions than on top of my custom marker I see another standard green maker with letter B.

How to overide that?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is use the suppressMarkers option of the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions), that will prevent it from adding any markers.

[Example with custom icons](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html), that doesn't use the DirectionsRenderer at all, it is from before that option was available.