# Google Map direction

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map on a website where I show the position of a business with a custom marker, also, I show the routes to get to the place but I can't seem to understand how to use a custom icon for the START position...

Here is the code I use:

```
<script>
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({draggable: true,suppressMarkers: true});
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.86140239,-74.062538);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom:13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: false,
                      panControl: false,
                      streetViewControl: false,
                      zoomControl: false,
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        // Marqueur sur le bureau
        var icon = {url: 'marker001c.png'};
        var headquartersMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: icon,
            zIndex:99999
        });

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }

    // Calcule de la route
    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = new google.maps.LatLng(45.86140239,-74.062538);
        var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
        });

        var starticon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('test.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:start,
            map: map,
            icon: starticon,
        });
        makeMarker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.17295,24.93981),
            content: "Some text in the info bubble.",
            title: "Tooltip text"
        });
    }
</script>
```

By using this code it show me the end icon (my main marker) but I can't change the start icon. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom icon for Google map API v3 directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430147/custom-icon-for-google-map-api-v3-directions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start` position as string could be used for `DirectionsService` but for marker you have to change position to `LatLng`.

See [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

For geocoding add new global variable:

```
...
var map;
var geocoder;
```

And initialize it:

```
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({draggable: true, suppressMarkers: true});
...
```

And get the latlng of the start 'address' after `directionsService.route()`:

```
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': start}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var starticon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/start.png');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map:   map,
                icon: starticon
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode failed with status: " + status);
        }
    });
```

See [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ojOrUNoj/1/edit). Note: it won't work there because I use my icon images so put in paths to your icon images.

Comment: my function calcroute() is just under **// Calcule de la route.**

Comment: But where and how you call it?

Comment: Well you loose me here, I am far from a Javascript pro, you can see my map here:http://boissilvac.ca/new/fr/infos/directions. Its working so I never had the idea that the code was incorrect...

Comment: Ok I removed the last marker call in the code (which was causing the **uncaught error**). Also I tested to add a the line `var start = new google.maps.LatLng(44.86140239, -73.062538);` and yes the custom marker appear at start position but how can I achieve this without a precise predifined start point?

Comment: ok, `initialize()` is called onload and `calcRoute()` is called with button click. And, btw, you change the code. You deleted `suppressMarkers: true` and left dangling comma.

Comment: Sorry I just did all the changes. The link I provided was the website but the code I pasted in my question was from offline testing...

Comment: Ok so if the custom marker shows correctly at START position with `var start = new google.maps.LatLng(44.86140239, -73.062538);`, what would be the syntax to call it without predefined latlng position?

Comment: OK, I think I figure it out: start position as string could be used for `DirectionsService` but for marker you have to change position to LatLng using geolocation.

Comment: I have to switch off. If you don't get it right from docs I will help later in an hour.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Anto its really appreciated. I will try all this later.

Comment: Wonderfull! Its working perfectly now. Thanks a million time for your help Anto!